# Activating Conda during Bash Script that Installing Anaconda

Tags: python, linux, bash, anaconda, conda

While trying to create a bash script that downloads and installs Anaconda/Miniconda, running the script results in the error

> setup.sh: line 7: conda: command not found

Was `source ~/.bashrc` not sufficient? How then should we activate Anaconda/Miniconda using the bash script so that `conda --version` (and other `conda` commands) can run without issues?

```
#!/bin/bash
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
mkdir /root/.conda
bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p $HOME/anaconda3
rm -f Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh 
source ~/.bashrc
conda --version
```

Running this in a Ubuntu 18.04 docker container, eventually it will be used on a Ubuntu 20.04+ server.

Comment: Miniconda already has pre-built Docker images. Consider having at look at [their Dockerfiles](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/docker-images) for a reference.

Answer (score 0):

After you have executed Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh, the commands like conda are located into the directory $HOME/anaconda3/bin, so you can do:

```
~/anaconda3/bin/conda --version
```

To add the path permanently in your ~/.bashrc:

```
~/anaconda3/bin/conda init
source ~/.bashrc
conda --version
```